# Why does jQuery has a "window=this" at the very begining and say it would speed up references to window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, lexical-scope

When I open jQuery's source code I find this line.

```
var 
// Will speed up references to window, and allows munging its name.
window = this
```

Why and how this line will speed up?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. [javascript functions have lexical scope](http://blogs.msdn.com/kartikb/archive/2009/01/15/lexical-scoping.aspx)
2. jQuery wraps its entire implementation in an [anonymous function](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/)
3. when said function begins execution it is executing in the "global" scope (ie `this` == `window`).

`"window = this;"` simply creates a local identifier in that scope so that references to it do not have to "bubble up" outside of the local scope to resolve.

Comment: Thanks. I just noticed that the code's running in a function scope.
(function(){var window=this;...})();

Answer (score 0):

`this` would be faster for javascript to reference to, as compared to `window` which would have to be resolved to the window object.