# Why has window and document been passed as parameters?

Tags: javascript

Modernizr starts with the following:

```
window.Modernizr = (function(window,document,undefined) { ...
```

...but why have window and document been passed as parameters? Is it something to do with differences between browsers? Or is it simply so the can't be redefined?

Comment: It makes it environment independent (more or less) and allows them to mock `window` and `document` for testing purposes.

Comment: exact duplicate of [What advantages does using (function(window, document, undefined) { ... })(window, document) confer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020479/what-advantages-does-using-functionwindow-document-undefined-windo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters when calling that function are the following: `(this, this.document)`
So it's guaranteed that `window` is the global object, `document` is the document object and `undefined` is undefined.

It also results in a small performance improvement; see [Why does jQuery has a "window=this" at the very begining and say it would speed up references to window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563875/why-does-jquery-has-a-window-this-at-the-very-begining-and-say-it-would-speed) for details

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's for efficiently. `window` and `document` don't have to be fetched every time Modernizr needs it, but rather, a cached version of it.